# Facebook Feed Dialog - Can we use the application logo as the image?

Tags: facebook

I'm using the [Facebook Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) to promote simple sharing on my website.

There is an option for the "picture" in the post (URL).

Is there a way i can use the existing logo in my Facebook application as the image?

[image]

[image]

For example is there a way i can programatically create a URL to my Facebook application logo? (using the application ID).

Comment: Looks like it's sharing a link. So why not just take advantage of the `og:image` tag?

Comment: @TommyCrush - please explain..

Comment: You choose the image on a per-post or per-object-instance basis, so just set it to whatever image you're using as the 75x75 image

Comment: but the point is, i don't want to double up on the maintenance of the logo. if i change the logo in the facebook application, i don't want to have to change it in my application. I'm using FB.ui to post to the feed...

Comment: Why you don't save the image on your server and use that image url to your feed dialog? Also @Alexander Nenkov answer is a nice solution in your situation.

Comment: @Philip - as per my comment above, i don't want to maintain two sets of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID
And then fetch the logo_url.

Edit: Just wanted to add that obviously apps in sandbox mode require access token to recognize you as admin/tester.

Comment: Woah, its working! Good to know, but earlier it was not allowed `FBCDN image is not allowed in stream` Ref: http://www.syndicatedmethods.com/SyndicatedBlogs/post/2010/06/22/FBCDN-image-is-not-allowed-in-stream-How-can-this-be.aspx

Comment: you can always make a workaround for this by creating a page that is passing the data from the FBCDN.

Comment: Yeah i found that URL, but as @Sahil said it's giving me that FBCDN error when i try and use it as the picture parameter. So with the workaround - i create a page/resource which returns the raw image - then use that as the parameter?

Comment: Hmm...i've got a resource returning the image, its like: "http://www.mysite.com/facebook/applicationlogo" and returns the image (content type = image/gif). But the facebook stream post doesn't like it. Just skips it. Any ideas? Does it need to have a file extension in the URI?

Comment: even when i save the file on my server and serve it directly from the filesystem, still doesn't show up. it's 75x75, so fits the requirements. don't know what the prob is...

Comment: nevermind, got it. i was serving the image on localhost - forgot that facebook can't access that. tried it on test live server - all good. +1 and accepted - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use that logo in your feed dialog, since its saved in the facebook server. (facebook don't allow that)

The straight-forward solution is - use the image from your server.

Comment: Does Facebook block images in share feeds coming from their domains?

Comment: It does previously. But now when i checked, it did not.